# What is the term between < and > called in Java?

Tags: java

I have seen a lot of times in Java constructs similar to:

```
List <String> myList = Arrays.asList("element1","element2","element3");
```

or

```
Map<Integer, String> map;
```

Now I want to know what this `<String>` or the <> signs is doing. Or especially what it is called so that I can search for it. All searches I have done before leading to operators. So can someone tell my how this is called?

Comment: "Java Generics" <--- type that keyword in Google

Comment: It's called a `template parameter`

Comment: *Is the code above the same like this?* No, absolutely not!

Comment: Thanks, then I can do research

Comment: Although now that I look at it, I have no idea what you are even trying to do in the second line of code.

Comment: You can create any type of List, list<Object>, List<MyClass>

Comment: @YassinHajaj: No, not at all.

Comment: "diamond operator" that's how its called. Didn't think about it.

Comment: Don't really understand why people downvote this. It's a valid question, isn't it?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? it's a legitimate question

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia i didn´t downvote it, but you can argue that this question didn´t provide any research effort, since the answers to this question can be searched quite easily

Comment: @KevinEsche it is if you know the term to search for, which is what he's asking. Googling "java term between < and >" doesn't provide any immediately useful result :/

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia search for `java what does "List<String>" mean`, you´ll get enough results that can lead you to the term `generics` quite fast.(second result does even have it in the title of the question). But you are right that it can be hard to find if you are using the wrong search terms.

Comment: @Kevin Esche Sure the answer is easy to find if you know what you are searching for. But not if you just finished a beginner tutorial which seems to not include everything of java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<> known as diamond operator. Declare type variables such as `<E>` using it and to pass [reference types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-ClassOrInterfaceType). Look for JLS section 4.4 [Type Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)

List interface declares a **type variable** `E` inside `<>` diamond operator.

`public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>`

When you do `List <String> myList` you actually passing a **Reference Type** or Type Parameter for `E`.

When you encounter empty `<>` on right hand side Java infers whatever type parameter is on left hand side of `=` operator.

You can understand it like you passed String type to `E` as its value using diamond operator like `<String>`. That's not true as Generics uses **Type Erasure** . You can send any type. As long as it satisfies bound on type Variable `E`.

As result its becomes a List of String objects.
If you send `<Object>` than it becomes the list of Objects.

Comment: Careful. IIRC Diamond operator is the Java7+ possibility to autoinfer the actual type, not the type parameter. Before Java7 you had to do "List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>", after 7 you can infer the right hand and do "List<String> list = new LinkedList<>".

Comment: I agree on right hand side Java infers whatever type parameter is on left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

That's generic type parameter(s)
See documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Or here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 1):

Java support the concept of generic types.

These are types that have a common behavior no matter what their type parameter is.

Immagine a List collection for example. A List is a sequential collection of elements, and a List of Integer is different than a List of Strings, but the basic logic is the same.

So instead of having two separate types ListOfInteger and ListOfString , Java has a List type, with a type parameter to specify what is the type of the elements

So the term between < and > is called type parameter, while List is a generic type.